# Although the "state" changes and the rendering function is executed, the elements are not properly plotted

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, drag-and-drop, shopify

I'm mutating the whole array, but changes are not applied fully in the page. I logged the variable and everything seems to be what I expect it to be.

I'm using the [react-shopify-draggable](https://github.com/wuweiweiwu/react-shopify-draggable) component for dragging and dropping.

**You can see [code on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/reactjs-change-state-obxoe)**

Comment: Your problem is not clear, what's the expected result ? I see that onclick the element is cloned

Comment: I can see that you have cloned the array, manipulated it, and set it again, that should be sufficient for react to know that the variable has changed